# Wifi not connected

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I installed ubuntu 16.04

Whenever I switch on WiFi from touch-pad nothing happens!!

Laptop specifications : hp pavillion dv4 ; 32-bit.
I am not able to connect via WiFi (wireless network).

Additional drivers installed:: 
Broadcom Corporation: BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY(BCM4312 802.11b/g wireless LAN controller)
Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernal-source(proprietary)

hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
soft blocked: no
hard blocked: no

Comment: Please check here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395  I believe you are using the incorrect driver.

Comment: must be driver problem.